# Changing Divs or Styles in CSS dynamically onSelect or Click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I have the following problem: I have an outer div and inner div that i need to change to match dynamically the sizing of my device properties. as you can see I have a click function that pulls the width and height in the title, but need to apply the sizing to the inner div, outer div and iframe at the same time as well as update the background image to match. I have tried some onclick functions for divs but no luck... The Fiddle has the CSS for the basic default view, just need to figure out how to apply on select or click of my select.
http://jsfiddle.net/jZJc3/

```
`<ul class="nav nav-pills left">
    <li class="dropdown">
 <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" id="device">Device</a>
   <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="devices">
<li data-deviceid=1><a href="#" onClick="ResizeElement()">iPad 768x1024h</a></li>
    <li data-deviceid=2><a href="#">iPhone 5 320x568h</a></li>
    <li data-deviceid=3><a href="#">iPhone 3-4 320x480h</a></li>
 <li data-deviceid=4><a href="#">Tablet 600x1024h</a></li>  
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
<div id="iphone"><div id="mobilecontent" class="mobilecontent">
<iframe id="ui_frame" src="http://voicefusion.com/iframe.htm" style="width:320px; height:480px;" class="mobilecontent" frameborder="0"></iframe>
</div>
</div>`
```

Comment: Anyone? even just an idea on changing one div?

Comment: I answered my own question...http://jsfiddle.net/W37nF/1/

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/W37nF/1/

Using hide class in CSS I was able to do what I needed....

```
$('select').on('change', function(){
var val = $(this).val();
$('div').hide();
$('.' + val).css('display','block'); }).change();
```